# How do I isolate debugging just to the current running project in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have just created a virtual directory and placed my app's files into it ready to allow some users to test.

The problem is when I then go to my visual studio project (which uses a different virtual directory when running and seperate code location) I get debug errors randomly appearing from my users actions.

How do I isolate debugging just to the current running project in visual studio?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: 5.1 , windows xp machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running IIS 5.1 you may need to use the [Visual Studio Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(VS.80).aspx) (aka Cassini) to host your Visual Studio Project.  This will isolate your project into a separate process  from what IIS uses (on Windows XP, IIS 5.1 uses "aspnet_wp.exe")

The default for new Web Application project types in Visual Studio is to use Cassini.  If for some reason you need to check or change it, open your project settings and verify it looks like this:

[Project Settings - Web http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1683/captureha.png](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1683/captureha.png)

Comment: I'm using authentication methodas that need access to our portal system  portal.website.com so i have been using iis as i can access the cookie data, mymachine.website.com  so not sure this would work. Any more ideas? i gave you +1 for answer anyway

Comment: This may already be obvious: try developing on a separate machine from your test server?  Another option would be to use IIS 6 on a Windows Server 2003 host.  You can isolate your virtual directories into separate app pools that way.